# Is it faster to use indices or names in Panda's "usecols"?

Tags: python, performance, csv, pandas

Say we have a (huge) csv file with a header "data".

I load this file with pandas (imported as pd):

```
pd_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
```

Now, say the file has multiple headers and many rows, so I would like to increase reading speed and reduce memory usage.

Is there a difference in performance between using:

```
(1) pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=['data'])
```

versus

```
(2) pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=0)
```

(let us assume that 'data' is always column 0).

The reason for using (1) is the piece of mind that no matter where 'data' is actually stored in the file we will load the right column.

Using (2) does require us to trust that column 0 is indeed 'data'.

The reason why I think (2) is faster is because (1) may have some overhead in looking for the column (unless it says "if match on first column, stop searching", kind of thing, of course).

**Questions:**

1. Which approach is faster among (1) and (2)?
2. Is there an even faster approach?

Thank you.

Comment: The speed should be approx. the same. If you want to speed it up you can GZIP or BZIP2 your file and read it archived - this will reduce disk IOs dramatically. Of course it makes sense only if you need to read the same file multiple times (zip ones, read many times), otherwise you will just lose time zipping it.

Comment: I would think that the mapping between column names and indices is set up right at the start of the reading process, and then when reading each row there's no real difference (except for maybe a very quick dict lookup). So, I don't think there'd be a big difference, but feel free to come up with a test if you want to be sure.